# File server using Ktor and Local Hotspot on android

Tags: android, kotlin, ktor

I am trying to create a server inside an android app. The idea is to create a Local Hotspot from the phone itself and start an HTTP server. Show instructions to users on how to connect to said Hotspot. Then an URL which when visited will automatically download file from the phone.

Server Thread

```
class Server(private val filePath: File): Thread() {
    override fun run() {
        val file = File(filePath, "test.txt")
        file.writeText("testing file")
        val server = embeddedServer(Netty, 8080) {
            routing {
                get("/") {
                    call.respondText { "Works" }
                }
                get("/files") {
                    call.respondFile(file, configure = {
                        this.setProperty(AttributeKey("Content-Disposition"), "attachment; filename=\"test.txt\"")
                    })
                }
            }
        }
        server.start(wait = true)
    }
}
```

Local Hotstop setup

```
        val mWifiManager = baseContext.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE) as WifiManager?
        mWifiManager?.startLocalOnlyHotspot(object : WifiManager.LocalOnlyHotspotCallback() {
            override fun onStarted(reservation: WifiManager.LocalOnlyHotspotReservation?) {
                super.onStarted(reservation)
                val wifiConfiguration = reservation?.wifiConfiguration
                if (wifiConfiguration != null) {
                    Log.d("testing", wifiConfiguration.preSharedKey)
                }
            }

            override fun onStopped() {
                Toast.makeText(baseContext, "STOP", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                super.onStopped()
            }

            override fun onFailed(reason: Int) {
                Toast.makeText(baseContext, "FAIL", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                super.onFailed(reason)
            }
        }, Handler())
```

gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.extermeprogramming.servertest"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    packagingOptions {
        pickFirst "META-INF/io.netty.versions.properties"
        exclude 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST'
    }
    
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

    // Ktor, HTTP SERVER
    ext.ktor_version = '1.3.2'
    implementation "io.ktor:ktor-server-core:$ktor_version"
    implementation "io.ktor:ktor-server-netty:$ktor_version"
    implementation "org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.9"

}
```

AndroidManifes

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.extermeprogramming.servertest" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.extermeprogramming.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/paths" />
        </provider>

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

When the Server and Hotspot is turned ON for the first time, the request to url 192.169.43.1:8080/files fails and the Hotspot turns OFF without calling any of the callbacks (onStopped, onFailed). When the Hotspot is enabled again everything works as expected and the file download without a problem and Hotspot stays turned ON.

The only error thrown is from Ktor which says `Call execution has been cancelled`. Changing the order of steps, first turning on Hotspot and then Server, results in the same exception. I think there is some configuration either in Ktor or in Hotspot which will fix this issue because after the exception when the Hotspot is turned on again everything works.